# How to import Sender Class - Java App Engine

Tags: android, google-app-engine, push-notification, google-cloud-messaging

I'm trying to implement Google cloud Messaging in my web application.
But when I write this :

```
Sender sender = new Sender("My API Key");
```

Then eclipse doesn't import anything on pressing ctrl+shift+o.

How to use this class ?

http://developer.android.com/reference/com/google/android/gcm/server/Sender.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using Maven for my java project (and since I couldn't find the references from the previous response), here's what I had to do (as stated in [this github GCM repo for maven](https://github.com/slorber/gcm-server-repository)).

Add this repository to your maven pom.xml:

```
<repositories>
    . . .
    <repository>
        <id>gcm-server-repository</id>
        <url>https://raw.githubusercontent.com/slorber/gcm-server-repository/master/releases/</url>
    </repository>
</repositories>
```

then add this dependency:

```
<dependencies>
    . . .
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.google.android.gcm</groupId>
        <artifactId>gcm-server</artifactId>
        <version>1.0.2</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

Then import it to your class:

```
import com.google.android.gcm.server.*;
```

To use it there is a mini example [here](http://www.androidcommunitydocs.com/google/gcm/helper.html#server-app) in the android GCM Server implementation docs.

---

**Update**

Since the example link is broken, I leave a short example here on which I make use of 2 business clases and 2 (or more) models to manage responses and messages:

*Sender.java*

```
public MulticastResult SendMessage(YourMessageObject yourMsg) throws IOException {
    Sender sender = new Sender(gcmApiKey); // A string
    String msg = yourMsg.getMessage();
    String msgTxt = (msg.isEmpty()) ? "This is a test" : msg ;

    Message message = new Message.Builder()
            .addData("title", "My title")
            .addData("message", msgTxt)
            .addData("msgCount", "3")
            .addData("jsonEvent", yourMsg.getEventJson())
            .build();

    if(devices.isEmpty()){
        return null;
    }
    return sender.send(message, devices, 5);
}
```

*GCMREsponseValidator.java*

```
public GCMResponseResume validateResponse(MulticastResult multicastResult, List<GCMClient> devices){
    String response;
    response = "multicast: " + multicastResult.toString();

    if(multicastResult.getMulticastId() != 0){
        responseResume = new GCMResponseResume(multicastResult);
        // We check the results
        int index = 0;
        List<Result> results = multicastResult.getResults();
        for(final Result result : results){
            // Si responde exitosamente
            if(result.getMessageId() != null){
                // If there is a canonical Id we replace the Id
                String canonicalRegId = result.getCanonicalRegistrationId();
                if (canonicalRegId != null) {
                    response = response.concat("\nCanonical found: " + canonicalRegId);
                    response = response.concat("\n... updating: " + devices.get(index));
                    Optional<GCMClient> currentDevice = Optional.of(devices.get(index));
                    String updated = clientsDAO.updateRegId(currentDevice, canonicalRegId);
                    response = response.concat("\n... updated: " + updated);
                        responseResume.addUpdatedIdsTotal(Integer.parseInt(updated));
                }
            }
            // If not a successful result
            else {
                String error = result.getErrorCodeName();
                // Y tiene error de no registrado, borramos el id correspondiente
                if (error.equals(Constants.ERROR_NOT_REGISTERED)) {
                    String notRegisteredId = devices.get(index).getRegisterId();
                    response = response.concat("\nNot Registered found: " + notRegisteredId);
                    response = response.concat("\n... deleting: " + notRegisteredId);
                    int removed = clientsDAO.removeByRegId(notRegisteredId);
                    response = response.concat("\n... deleted:" + Integer.toString(removed));
                    responseResume.addDeletedIdsTotal(removed);
                }
            }
            index++;
        }

        response = response.concat("\nResults: " + results.toString());
    }

    return responseResume;
}
```

where resonseResume is this model:
*GCMResponseMResume*

```
public class GCMResponseResume {
    private MulticastResult multicastResult;
    private int updatedCanonicalIdsTotal;
    private int deletedIdsTotal;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You should add `gcm-server.jar` (located at `<Your Android SDK Dir>\extras\google\gcm\gcm-server\dist\gcm-server.jar`) to your eclipse project.

You can do it by right clicking on the project and selecting `Properties -> Java Build Path -> Libraries -> Add External JARs...`

Comment: I'm no able to find gcm-server.jar in my android sdk folders.

Comment: @omerjerk You have to install the Google Cloud Messaging for Android Library (go to the Android SDK Manager - you'll find it close to the bottom under Extras).

Comment: Deprecated is written there .. That's why I didn't install it.

Comment: @omerjerk The client library is deprecated (though it still works), but the server library isn't.

Comment: There is no Google Cloud Messaging under Extras. I have downloaded adt-bundle-windows-x86_64-20131030

Comment: Scratch that I found it after checking obsolete box.